# Why is the backspace/del event in an html input breaking my html?

Tags: html, mobile, cordova

I'm doing a Phonegap app and I have this weird issue when doing a backspace or delete key press in the text input. The text input takes 100% width, and if my string is longer than the mobile screen and i backspace/del in the input, it breaks my html layout, it brings my header above the text input to the top left position of the input element. Here are 2 images of what's happening. If my string is small, the backspace/del doesn't break my html.

[image]
[image]

This is the css and html I have for my input:

```css
.dentry {color: #000000;font-size: 2.6em}

#dentry-wrap {width:100%; height:80px; margin:0 0 7px 0;}
.inputareafull {
    width:100%; height:80px; float:left; font-size:2.6em;
    border-top-left-radius:3px; -moz-border-radius-topleft:3px; border-bottom-left-radius:3px; -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:3px;
    border-top:1px solid #c4c4c4; border-bottom:1px solid #fff;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgb(247, 247, 247)), to(rgb(222, 225, 225)));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(247, 247, 247), rgb(222, 225, 225));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgb(247, 247, 247), rgb(222, 225, 225));
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgb(247, 247, 247), rgb(222, 225, 225));
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgb(247, 247, 247), rgb(222, 225, 225));
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgb(247, 247, 247), rgb(222, 225, 225));
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,StartColorStr='#f7f7f7', EndColorStr='#dee1e1');
}
.inputareafull input {width:98%; height:100%; text-align: left; background:none; border:none;}
```

```html
<div id="dentry-wrap">
    <div class="inputareafull">
        <input class="dentry"></input>
    </div>
</div>
```

I didn't do the CSS stuff and I'm not 100% what could be causing this.

Any help is appreciated thanks!

Comment: Another weird thing about this issue is that if I click on the top left or top right corner where it's blank, it still does the click event for my buttons and it re-redirects accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It was caused by my container around the dentry-wrap div, I removed it and set my margins properly on the inputareafull div and now it works.